# Sitecore AdvancedDatabaseCrawler advantages/benefits

Tags: database, search, module, sitecore, web-crawler

I tried using Sitecore.Search namespace and it seems to do basic stuff. I am now evaluating AdvancedDatabaseCrawler module by Alex Shyba. What are some of the advantages of using this module instead of writing my own crawler and search functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advantages**:

- You don't have to write anything.
- It handles a lot of the code you need to write to even query Sitecore, e.g. basic search, basic search with field-level sorting, field-level searches, relation searches (GUID matches for lookup fields), multi-field searches, numeric range and date range searches, etc.
- It handles combined searches, with logical operators
- [You can access the code](http://svn.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler/Branches/v2/).
- [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=m9av3C_tPH8) shows samples of the code and front-end running various search types.

**Disadvantages**:

- None that I can think of, because if you find an issue or a way to extend it, you have full access to the code and can amend it per your needs. I've done this before by creating the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` methods for the `SkinnyItem` class.

Comment: I implemented it and can already see some benefits. I wasn't able to get sorting to work using Sitecore.Search on a date field but this module works flawless with it's special indexing of the date fields.

Have you noticed any issues with caching, publishing and the index getting updated when an item is edited or published? I just have a fear that the index might not get updated automatically and I might have to write something custom to force the crawler to update the index.

Comment: Explain your environments. Do you have just one instance? More than one, with 1 CM and 1 CD? Multiple CDs? There's definitely additional configuration for those, but I can give you some pointers.

Comment: There is one CM and 3 CDs. The piece of the page using Lucene will be using Sitecore caching (varied by data and querystring).

Comment: We are also looking into using Lucene heavily for the future enhancements to the site.

Comment: If you have more than one CD, you absolutely must read this article: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/04/search-index-troubleshooting.html -- if not configured correctly, CD instance's will not rebuild indexes.

Comment: I got one more question. Say for example, I have a sublayout that uses a lucene index and is also cached to vary by data. Would the sublayout automatically update when new data is available in the lucene index?

Comment: Great question. It caches the final HTML for the data item (either an explicit data source or the context item). If the index changes after the HTML cache exists, it will not show it updated. One option is don't cache it, another is to do some C# to cache by last index change data time (a bit complicated).

Comment: Do you have some code sample I can refer for last index change date time?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the "old" way of acecssing the Lucene index was very simple, but unfortunately it's deprecated from Sitecore 6.5.
The "new" way of accessing the Lucene index is very complex as the possibilities are endless. Alex Shyba's implementation is the missing part that makes it sensible to use the "new" way.

Take a look at this blog post: http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/using-the-sitecore-open-source-advanceddatabasecrawler-lucene-indexer/

It's a 3 part description on how to configure the AdvancedDatabaseCrawler, how to make a simple search and how to make a multi field search. Without Alex's AdvancedDatabaseCrawler, these tasks would take almost 100 lines of code. With the AdvancedDatabaseCrawler, it takes only 7 lines of code.

So if you are in need of an index solution, this is the solution to use.